# Uncaught Type Error - fadeToggle/Display, Jquery (It works but still throws the error)

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, fade

So I've got this function;

```
function hoverTiles() {
  $('.content-block').hover(function () {
      var $content = $('.content', this);
       $content.fadeToggle(1000, 'linear').display(1000, 'linear');
  });
}
```

But chrome is telling me I have an Uncaught Type Error even though the function itself is working? If I remove the fadeToggle I get the same error but with display instead.

Any insight much appreciated. Even though it's working I was told never to ignore errors...

console log:

> custom.js:82 Uncaught TypeError: $content.fadeToggle(...).display is not a function
>           at HTMLDivElement. (custom.js:82)
>           at HTMLDivElement.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
>           at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
>           at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
>       (anonymous) @ custom.js:82
>       handle @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
>       y.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2

Comment: If you click the error in the Chrome console it will take you to the line which is causing the problem.

Comment: Hi Rory just added the console log. Line 82 is the  $content.fadeToggle(1000, 'linear').display(1000, 'linear');

Comment: Thanks for posting the full error. It tells you what's wrong - jQuery has no `display()` method. I assumed you were using a third party library for that. What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: Thank you! Solved it. I have just been going over something I wrote a while ago and I couldn't work it out because I assumed display was a jQuery method. Thanks man.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.